# Software for matching spectral end members with spectral library

Tags: remote-sensing, software-recommendations, hyperspectral-sensor

I am working with Moon Mineralogy mapper(M3) - hyper-spectral data and i am trying to match the endmembers obtained from M3 with RELAB spectral library. I have tried spectral analyst tool in ENVI but failed to match spectra due to spectral mixing of pixels. I am looking for a software or module or technique that matches each endmember with various possible materials from spectral library.

Comment: Isn't this more or less what a technique like Spectral Angle Mapper (SAM) does? https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/SpectralAngleMapper.html Any progress here?

Comment: yeah, SAM matches spectral signatures of endmembers from image with spectral library..... but the spectral signature of end members are mixed ... You will have to use advanced technique to unmix or deconvolve the mixed endmembers to find the percentage of each material in it .